# What set does this Lego S.W.A.T van go to?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands

I found this in my wife's closet when I was trying to look for my dress shoes. I want to know if this is worth anything and what set this goes to.
Sorry if it's dusty. There is also a little gun that goes to it, can anyone tell me what it is from?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are guaranteed to be from clone-brands. Lego does not make such militaristic content.

Comment: Do the studs have the word "Lego" on them? If not then that means they are from clone-brand. This also looks like a custom MOC of official Lego parts as well as clone-brand pats too, so I don't think we will be able to identify it (but it's worth a try maybe). Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: I cannot see if vehicle does have LEGO logo on studs, but it looks like either MOC or clone-brand set. Too dark and oddly shaped for a LEGO set.

Comment: @mindstormsboi It does say "LEGO" on the top, and that is sort of the reason why i asked this question cause its is hart to tell what this set comes from

Comment: @mindstormsboi i sent it again

Answer (score 2):

That gun is actually pure Lego. It's a [Tommy Gun](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x1608&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Gun,%20Pistol%20Automatic%20Long%20Barrel%20and%20Round%20Magazine%20(Tommy%20Gun)&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=C).

[image: tommy gun]

Your truck, however, seems like a custom MOC made of random clone-brand parts due to the randomness and low quality of the build. I doubt that a clone-brand company would publish that truck as a set if it looked like that.

I am currently failing to identify this part on your truck, it doesn't match the color scheme. It proves that your truck is made of multiple clone-brand parts from multiple sets, and maybe even multiple companies! I can not find anything like it in the google image search:

[image: swat]

The closest I can find is this part, and [here's the site it's hosted on](https://www.custombricks.de/CUSTOM-Instructions/City-Minifigscale/City-SWAT-Minifig-scale/SWAT-SW03-BA-EN.html?language=en):

[image: swat2]

From the comments:
[You have also said that it says Lego on the studs](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/14985/what-set-does-this-lego-s-w-a-t-van-go-to?noredirect=1#comment18213_14985), but I'm just going to assume that only **some** of them do because of that clone-brand part I've pointed out. Lego does not and will not make SWAT content, and besides that, the truck is a rather low-quality build, so it's certainly not "from a set". Why randomly put a lattice tile on the roof like that anyway? Why do you need two sets of headlights? And why is there a 4x4 round plate on the roof when you can simply access from the back instead? It makes me conclude this is a MOC.

Comment: Comments are not the place for extended discussion. Previous comments have been moved to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109594/discussion-on-answer-by-mindstormsboi-what-set-does-this-lego-s-w-a-t-van-go-to